# Iterate through object inside an object within constructor function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, constructor

Within constructor function I am trying to create an object.

Within the object I am already using map function for some arrays.

Challenge appeared when I tried to iterate through an object, since I cannot use map function on object. I also tried using `for in` function inside this object but it appears, it is not valid JS to use `for in` within object creation.

My goal is to iterate through `individualData` object (just like normal map function for arrays).

I tried moving `data: data.individualData` inside map function. That did not work for my expected result.

Here is my code:

```js
labelsArray = ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner'];

data = {
  miniLabelsArray: ['Egg', 'Soup', 'Steak'],
  type: ['Vegetarian', 'Vegan', 'Normal'],
  individualData: [{
    John: ['1', '2', '3'],
    Paul: ['10', '20', '30'],
    Kate: ['100', '200', '300']
  }]
};

function CreateData(data, someNewObj) {
  
  this.someNewObj = {
    labels: labelsArray,
    datasets: 
      data.miniLabelsArray.map((miniLabelsArray, i) => ({
        miniLabel: data.miniLabelsArray[i],
        type: data.type[i],
        })),
        data: data.individualData
    };
  };

var testing = new CreateData(data);

console.log('testing', testing.someNewObj);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoMdoe?editors=1111

Expected result:

```
 ...
  "datasets": [
    {
      "miniLabel": "Egg",
      "type": "Vegetarian",
      "data": ["1", "2", "3"]       // DIFFERENCE HERE
    },
    {
      "miniLabel": "Soup",
      "type": "Vegan",
      "data": ["10", "20", "30"]       // DIFFERENCE HERE
    },
    {
      "miniLabel": "Steak",
      "type": "Normal",
      "data" :["100", "200", "300"]       // DIFFERENCE HERE
    }
  ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried for...of for your loop? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: @Doug I tried within the object itself (inside), but it is not a valid JS?

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to move `data: ...` inside your `.map()` function, and say `data: individualData[0][Object.keys(individualData[0])[i]]`. It's super awkward, and the property order cannot always be guaranteed in the object.keys(), but it would work.

Comment: @mhodges if the order can't be guaranteed, is there any other way to do it, to guarantee the order? I guess doing it outside the object as a for in function may be an option?

Comment: @lovemyjob It depends on your use-case. If knowing that `[1, 2, 3]` is specifically "John"s data, then you can have a separate array of names, like so: `data.names = ["John", "Paul", "Kate"]` and your individual data would be `[["1", "2", "3"], ["10", "20", "30"], ...]` then you can just access `data.individualData[i]` and you have guaranteed order. If you need the names associated with it, you can tack on `name: data.names[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your method into This.

```
datasets: data.miniLabelsArray.map((value, index)=>({
  miniLabel: value,
  type: data.type[index],
  data: data.individualData[0][keys[index]]
}))
```

The important thing here is `var keys = Object.keys(data.individualData[0])`

and `data: data.individualData[0][keys[index]]`

```js
labelsArray = ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner'];

data = {
  miniLabelsArray: ['Egg', 'Soup', 'Steak'],
  type: ['Vegetarian', 'Vegan', 'Normal'],
  individualData: [{
    John: ['1', '2', '3'],
    Paul: ['10', '20', '30'],
    Kate: ['100', '200', '300']
  }]
};

function CreateData(data, someNewObj) {
  //get keys from [individualData] property
  var keys = Object.keys(data.individualData[0])
  this.someNewObj = {
    labels: labelsArray,
    // here we map every [miniLabelsArray] value and get the [type] and [individualData] depending on the index that we are.
    datasets: data.miniLabelsArray.map((value, index)=>({
      miniLabel: value,
      type: data.type[index],
      // here we get the real key of [data.individualData] using the key we took at the beginning like this : keys[index], and with that key we get the value in [data.individualData[0]]
      data: data.individualData[0][keys[index]]
    }))
      
    };
  };

var testing = new CreateData(data);

console.log('testing', testing.someNewObj);
```

Comment: Hi, any word of explanation, why this works, please?

Comment: I Added some explanation in the code. I did the same as you did just that i added `data: data.individualData[0][keys[index]]` and `var keys = Object.keys(data.individualData[0])` to be able to get the real key of the `individualData` array

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an `individualdata` array containing only the numbers like this:

```
let individualdata = [];
for (let d in data.individualData) { 
    individualdata.push(data.individualData[d]);
}
```

Put this at the top of your `CreateData()` function and replace `data: data.individualData` with `data: individualdata`

Comment: individualData is an array, all you're doing here is pushing the entire object into a new array - this doesn't help. Should be `for (let d in data.individualData[0]) { ... }`